# I'm not losing weight

Tags: weight-loss, metabolism

I'm not losing weight instead I'm gaining 
I've been on calorie diet with range 1300 or 1200 
With workout for 5 days per week and also lifting weight 
But I'm not losing weight !!
I Donnu what's wrong with my body someone can help

Comment: How long have you been trying, how old/tall/heavy are you, how do you track your "diet" (don't do diets)? Please be aware that unless you want to enter some sort of competition you most likely want to lose fat and not weight. Have you tracked your body fat percentage?

Comment: A random 25 y/o female that is 100 lbs and 5'5 has a BMR of ~ 1500 calories. I doubt that you are really at 15-20% less than that while working out and not losing weight. I think you are vastly underestimating your actual calories, or are completely unaware of actually constitutes a real portion size.

Comment: No my calories r between 1200 to 1300 and I'm using kitchen scale I lift weights and do cardio workout my weight is 100 and my tall is 164 cm

Comment: If you're lifting 5 days a week, then you probably need to eat more. Yes, I know if sounds counter intuitive, but try and calculate your daily energy expenditure, take 250 from that value, and eat that for a few weeks and see what happens. If you don't lose, take another 200 and try again. If you do lose, then stick at it for a while.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already done so, start a food journal.  Most people underestimate how many calories they are consuming.  Guessing at what you are eating while trying to lose weight will not help.  Use the food journal to record what you eat and drink for a structured period of time.  Then, look where you can slowly cut calories from your diet until you reach your goal weight.  Set a goal weight that is realistic.  Don't expect to lose a lot of weight all at once.  It's not healthy, and, in the long term, is counter productive.

Structure your lifting around a strength training program that includes some form of aerobics.  Adding muscle mass will help you burn more calories.

Whatever you do, don't give up!

Comment: Yes. You may be counting them wrong, so a journal will help. Additional muscle will also burn more calories which will help you burning fat. I would also recommend taking mirror as a reference. It is possible that you are gaining muscle (if you are new to weight training) and that may be the reason you do not see any change on the scale.

Answer (score -2):

Depends on the exercise you do.Swimming ,running the best workouts for losing fast weight and gaining muscle.Drink a lot of water than eating is good solution too.Instead of getting an answer of why you don't lose weight try to do more workout. Example,morning go walking 6kilometers or running. Eat cornflakes, continue,after 2 hours go bicycle,sleep well go swimming,1 kilometer is good.Lifting is not for me the best solution to lose weight. Move as possible as you can.This is the best solution.Even more,if you are beginner don't try  what I wrote .Do 2 kilometers for start.Run 20minutes (if you get tired ,walk and continue).Swim 200meters.Don't accept my answer.Try to do this or a similar program like that and after 2-3 days come back.Try eating 1 meal ,increase vegetables and fruits. I hope I helped we will see

Comment: Your answer is somewhat scattered and based on personal opinion.  What works for you, may not work for others.